# How to Implement Spring Boot with EntityManager

Tags: spring-boot

I'm new to Spring Boot, I saw in Spring Boot by default JpaRepository use for database operation but I want to use EntityManager, I used following settings in `applicaition.properties` file.

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://xxxx:3306/my_db?useSSL=false&UseUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=xxx
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none
```

When I try to deploy my Spring Boot app it stops straight away without throwing any exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change configuration little bit for this,

just chnage as following

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.username = xxxx
spring.datasource.password = xxxx
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
```

For More details, refer following link here is common SpringBoot properties

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html